# Applying CSS to single div class/id

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble containing CSS to a single div without scrambling everything.
I'm trying to get hospital/name/title/dep on seperate lines(vertical) with aligned text boxes then the other sections on the same line respectively(horizontal)

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
<div class="main" id="boxalign">
            <p>
                <label>Hospital:</label> <input type="text"/><br>       
                <label>Name:</label> <input type="text"/><br>
                <label>Title:</label> <input type="text"/><br>  
                <label>Department:</label> <input type="text"/><br>
            </p>
         </div>
```

CSS

```
#boxalign, label p{
display: inline-block;
float: left;
clear: left;
width: 70px;
text-align: right;
```

}

Not sure if my problem really shows with the code above so heres all of in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f8qa2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just have a rouge ,  and your p and label are the wrong way round in your selector.

Try

```
#boxalign p label{
display: inline-block;
float: left;
clear: left;
width: 70px;
text-align: right;
}
```

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/f8qa2/12/)

Comment: CSS doesnt seem to apply when trying. thanks for the idea though

Comment: The backwards 'p' seemed to be the problem. I was sure it was something simple with syntax but needed some more eyes, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I think your CSS selector is malformed, try this instead:

```
#boxalign label p {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    width: 70px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Also, rather than use `<br>`s to break lines, put each `<label>`/`<input>` pair in it's own `<p>`:

```
<div class="main" id="boxalign">
    <p>
        <label>Hospital:</label>
        <input type="text" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input type="text" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Title:</label>
        <input type="text" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Department:</label>
        <input type="text" />
    </p>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chrispickford/f8qa2/1/)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you meant to put that comma there, everything looks good without it.

```
#boxalign label p{
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    width: 70px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

[**Link**](http://jsfiddle.net/f8qa2/10/)

`#boxalign, label p` Means that you want to target elements with the id `boxalign` and `p` tags within `labels`.

`#boxalign label p` Means that you want to target `p` tags within `labels` with a parent element with the id `boxalign`.

Comment: CSS doesn't apply with comma taken out. trying to align the first 4 items text boxes. while it looks 'unscrambled' thats just the result of trying to align the text boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is wrong. It should be `#boxalign p label {}`.

`label` and `p` are round the wrong way based on your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

remove the unceccesary "," from the css selector.

Hope that helps.